# Partially overriding view config inherit from parent class in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I am using class based views to cut down the amount of repeating oneself in similar view methods. Pyramid `@view_config` allows to do this with little boilerplate. Example when I have the same the view where only the context changes:

```
class BaseEdit(FormView):

    @view_config(context=Resource, name="edit", renderer="crud/edit.html", permission='edit')
    def edit(self):
        pass

class UserEdit(BaseEdit):

    @view_config(context=UserResource, name="edit", renderer="crud/edit.html", permission='edit')
    def edit(self):
        pass
```

However, would it be possible to reduce this boilerplate even further? E.g. I don't want to re-declare the `template` file, because it doesn't change. I want only the change some the `@view_config` parameters. Is there a way to say something like this:

```
class BaseEdit(FormView):

    @view_config(context=Resource, name="edit", renderer="crud/edit.html", permission='edit')
    def edit(self):
        pass

class UserEdit(BaseEdit):

    @view_override(context=UserResource)
    def edit(self):
        pass
```

Any other suggested patterns to make it so that I can vary only some parameters, namely `context`, for generic views?

The following **does not** work:

```
@view_defaults(context=UserResource, template="foobar.html")
class UserEdit(BaseEdit):
    pass
```

In this case it still uses orignal `@view_config` and ignores the overridden template.

Or:

```
@view_defaults(context=UserResource)
class UserEdit(BaseEdit):

    def edit(self):
        # This is never called
        return "xx"
```

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728780/pyramid-view-class-inheritance-with-view-defaults-and-view-config-decorators ?

Comment: @matino: Looks very promising! Will check it out if it solves my use case.

Comment: @matino: Looks like `@lift` did not do any good for my use case, but might be a step to right direction

Comment: To be more specific - looks like `@view_config()` from parent class is executed before `view_defaults` can do anything resulting to `pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationConflictError: Conflicting configuration actions` - as both parent and child class have the same view_config signature

Answer (score 0):

As the current state of the art could not cut it, I went ahead and created a little helper function and package `@view_overrides`:

- https://bitbucket.org/websauna/websauna.viewconfig

Answer (score 0):

The following should work and do what you think. Specifically the second `@view_defaults` should override the previous one. `@view_config` may not be over-riden in the same way IIRC.

```
from venusian import lift

@view_defaults(context=Resource)
class BaseEdit(FormView):

    @view_config(name="edit", renderer="crud/edit.html", permission='edit')
    def edit(self):
        pass

@view_defaults(context=UserResource)
@lift()
class UserEdit(BaseEdit):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However you need to redeclare the `@view_config()` line which is what I especially wanted to avoid.

Comment: Sorry, you shouldn't need to redo the `@view_config()` line so long as you don't have to change any part of it.

Comment: I appreciate for your effort, but it still doesn't do what I want. For example, you could not override `name=edit` from the earlier class without fully specifying `@view_config`. Please for further questions refer to websauna.viewconfig README https://bitbucket.org/websauna/websauna.viewconfig

Comment: Your `websauna.viewconfig` doesn't show any concrete examples of `@view_config` being overriden. You only show the `context` being replaced. My example above will do that, without needing to write a custom `lift()` method.

Comment: Best part is that if all of the views can use the same renderer, you can also place that in the `view_defaults`, same thing with `route_name`. The only thing you can't is the `name` of a view.

Comment: Let's say that I tested it comprehensively before writing a custom `lift()`